# Cannot define a computation expression custom "condition" operator

Tags: f#, computation-expression, custom-operator

I am having serious difficulty coming up with a definition for `condition` in the following code. Hoping for an example and insight:

```
// a computation expression builder class
type Builder() =
    .
    .
    .

    [<CustomOperation( "condition",
      MaintainsVariableSpaceUsingBind = true )>]
    member this.Condition(p, [<ProjectionParameter>] b) = 
        condition p b

let attemp = AttemptBuilder()

let test =
    attempt { let x, y = exp1, exp2
              condition booleanExpr(x, y)   
              return (x, y) }
```

I presume `b` is implicitly `( fun x, y -> booleanExpr(x, y) )`. The term `booleanExpr(x, y)` is just some Boolean expression involving `x` and `y`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Also, see [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is it ... on page 475 of Expert F# 4.0, you could see this example for a custom conditional operator to replace `if`/`then`. The value`condition` is not specifically defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found It:

```
let condition p guard = ( fun () ->
    match p() with
    | Some x when guard x -> Some x
    | _ -> None )
```